# How to make the export slices equally large as the artboard size in Affinity Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer

I created some artboards in Affinity Designer, and gave each artboard a specific height and width. I also want to export each artboard, so I changed to the Export Persona, but to my surprise, the slice has a different size than what I expected (from the screenshots in this question, the Export Persona slice added one pixel to the width). How can I make sure that the Export Persona is using the same size as in the Designer Persona?

For only one artboard, I would just change the size manually, but I have 64 artboards!

I am using Affinity Designer 1.8.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my artboards were not aligned pixel perfect, and the slices need to guess the width and height because of it, thus 1 pixel error occured.

I posted my question on the [Affinity Forum](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/109799-export-persona-slices-have-different-sizees-than-the-artboards-in-designer-persona/&tab=comments#comment-593342), and I got help from someone there, who pointet it out for me.

I ended up creating a new document, forcing pixel alignment from the start, and now the slices are correct.